Testing a BinData field by $bitAllSet with an offset and size limit in MongoDB
Assume I have a BinData field of arbitrary length that stores n-byte items. The offset of each item is known before the query and all items are n bytes. I want to test an item at offset X with bitmask Y. It is important to mention that I don't want to do a search, just a bitmask test, for the offset is known.
Currently, I'm reading the whole field and testing on my server side.
Is there a way to do it on MongoDB side?

From what I see in the question, it still needs clarification about why you need to point out the offset as well because I assume you can directly point out to the bitmask position as reflected below:
The following query uses the $bitsAllSet operator to test whether field a has bits set at positions 4 and 5 (the binary representation of BinData(0, "MA==") is 00110000).
db.collection.find( { a: { $bitsAllSet: BinData(0, "MA==") } } )

The query matches the following document:
{ _id: 1, a: 54, binaryValueofA: "00110110" }

Source: MongoDB documentation

Thanks for your comment! The binary data can be much larger than a 32-bit mask. Say I have a 108 bytes array buffer, and I want to check the 84-th byte... I still have a mask of 1 byte, but the offset would be 83...
